# Nearley. How to resolve grammar Nearley use JS syntax

Tags: javascript, parsing, lexer, moo, nearley

Let's say I have some kind of grammar, but it works by itself, but the JS code does not recognize it. Is there such an option so that you can combine the code of your grammar and syntax in one.

Let's say I have this grammar (Nearley + Moo).

```
@{%
const lexer = moo.compile({
   start_tag: "<",
   tag: /A-Z.../,
   close_tag: ">"
})
%}

elemcreation -> "<" %tag ">"
```

That is, my grammar recognizes such this syntax, and works only with it, but how can I make it possible to write and combine the syntax of my grammar and the grammar of the JS itself. That is JSX i want to do it in JS.

That is:

// my grammar syntax

`"< tag >"`

// js grammar syntax

`"const mycon = "Hello, world!";"`

How to make it possible to combine them, but not by defining the entire js syntax in nearley

Comment: в You're off topic, you won't understand

Comment: Good luck, Tim.

Comment: ok, mplungjan!.

Comment: you need to write (or find) a javascript grammar, look where it describes possible literal values (strings, numbers etc) and add your `<...>` rule to that list.

Comment: I'm aware, I know how to do it, and that's not the problem, the problem is that JS doesn't support JSX syntax.

Comment: And, I want to make this support, if I write it, it will only support JSX, and I want to combine it!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a wildcard pattern to capture the characters you don't care about into a token & specify how that token fits into the rest of your grammar.

Here is an example nearley grammar file that captures characters before, in the middle and outside of the open & close tag.

```
@{%
const moo = require('moo');

const lexer = moo.compile({
   open_tag: /\<[a-zA-Z0-9_]+\>/,
   close_tag: /\<\/[a-zA-Z0-9_]+\>/,
   bodyless_tag: /\<[a-zA-Z0-9_]+\/\>/,
   left_arrow : /\</,
   something: { match:/[^\<]+/, lineBreaks:true}
})
%}

@lexer lexer

main        -> something_ elem something_
               {% (d) =>  [ d[0], ...d[1], d[2] ] %}

elem        -> %open_tag something_ %close_tag
               {% (d) => [ d[0], d[1], d[2] ] %}

something_   -> %something:* {% (d) => d[0][0] %}
```

On this JSX snippet...

```
    const jsx = <h1>This is JSX</h1>; 
    const mycon = "Hello, world!
```

This is output using nearley-test. Some properties are truncated for brevity.

```
 [
  [
    { type: 'something', value: 'const jsx = ' },
    { type: 'open_tag', value: '<h1>' },
    { type: 'something', value: 'This is JSX'    },
    { type: 'close_tag', value: '</h1>' },
    { type: 'something', value: '; \nconst mycon = "Hello, world!\n' }
  ]
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this project](https://github.com/basescriptnet/BaseScript.lang). It basically reimplements a JS like syntax with html support in it. At the same time, take a look at Nearley itself. It uses it's own syntax, and simply separates JS/TS/Coffee code with `@{% %}` or `{% %}` symbols. You could do the same, but in the opposite direction. Write JavaScript, and separate your syntax with `<tag>`, or `(<tag>)`, as it would be much easier to implement. There is no way for this to be valid code. Next step is translating this code into JavaScript, and insert it in place of Nearley grammar. Hope this helped.

Comment: Heh, hello by markow